# Proper way to pass cutoff_time to dfs in featuretools 1.0.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, featuretools

Recently I've updated featuretools to v1.0.0 and faced the following issue. I have instances that vary within time and I want to build time dependent features for them. Besides, I want to save some historical characteristics of those instances. So my cutoff time dataset consists of such columns as: time, instance_id and feature1, feature2, ..., target

When I tried to to run dfs, I got the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'logical_types'`

I have found out that it is caused by the inner function `get_ww_types_from_features`

It tries to get the column types of cutoff time df, assuming it has woodwork type

```
        cutoff_schema = cutoff_time.ww.schema
        for column in pass_columns:
            logical_types[column] = cutoff_schema.logical_types[column]
            semantic_tags[column] = cutoff_schema.semantic_tags[column]
            origins[column] = "base"
```

But originally cutoff time is pandas DataFrame and I haven't found the place in code where it is translated into woodwork. And also it is said in the documentation that it is ok to pass cutoff time as pandas DataFrame

As a result, my question is: what is a proper way to pass cutoff time DataFrame (if it is pandas then is where a mistake in code?) (or if there is no mistake, then should I transform cutoff time to wood work manually in code before dfs?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Featuretools 1.0.0 when using a dataframe for `cutoff_time` that has additional columns (e.g. labels) and using multiple workers via the `n_jobs` or `dask_kwargs` options.  This may be the issue you are encountering.  This bug has been fixed in Featuretools 1.1.0

A pandas df is meant to be accepted for `cutoff_time` in 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
cutoff_times = pd.DataFrame()
cutoff_times['customer_id'] = [1, 2, 3, 1]
cutoff_times['time'] = pd.to_datetime(['2014-1-1 04:00',
                             '2014-1-1 05:00',
                             '2014-1-1 06:00',
                             '2014-1-1 08:00'])
cutoff_times['label'] = [True, True, False, True]
cutoff_times
fm, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,`enter code here`
                      target_dataframe_name='customers',
                      cutoff_time=cutoff_times,
                      cutoff_time_in_index=True)
fm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do the exact same way and it doesn't work in my case 
It worked in 0.0.24, but now it doesn't

Comment: I think the version of the tech plays major role here.